# Using multi select in one insert query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a `query` which have to check before doing insertion 2 things-

1. User that is about to bid is not the last bidder
2. Bid amount increase by USD 1

Below is the query i have tried to write:

```
insert into auc_bit_history (last_bid_amt,userid,aucid,bit_coin,datemade,updated_at) 
select IFNULL(max(1+1),1) as bidamount,6,911,1,'2018-03-07 19:22:48','2018-03-07 19:22:48' 
from auc_bit_history 
where aucid=911 and userid!=(
    select if(count(*)=0,0,userid) as lastbidderId  
    from auc_bit_history 
    where aucid=911 
    order by id 
    desc limit 0,1)
```

This part of my query is working fine:

```
insert into auc_bit_history (last_bid_amt,userid,aucid,bit_coin,datemade,updated_at) 
select IFNULL(max(1+1),1) as bidamount,6,911,1,'2018-03-07 19:22:48','2018-03-07 19:22:48' 
from auc_bit_history 
where aucid=911
```

But now i also want to check last bidder is not the same user:

```
select if(count(*)=0,0,userid) as lastbidderId  
from auc_bit_history where aucid=911 
order by id desc 
limit 0,1
```

Some how i need to merge all these in one query without using `left/right join`

Please help me out here.

Comment: Why do you have to do it without using `JOIN`?

Comment: `MAX(1+1)`? Shouldn't it be `MAX(bidamount+1)`?

Comment: Inner join can be used

Comment: It's easier to do exclusions using outer join. Why can't you use that?

Comment: sure, can you share some sample ?

Comment: Where is the "user who is about to bid" in your queries?